# Why does this combination of curly braces and double quotes not work in bash?

Tags: bash, variables, double-quotes, expansion, pathname

I'm trying to understand how to use curly braces and quotes properly in bash.  I'm wondering why the third example of an ls command doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash -vx

# File name prefix.
File_name_prefix='this_is_a_file_name_prefix'

# Let's do this in the /tmp directory.
cd /tmp

# Let's make three empty files.
touch ${File_name_prefix}_1.txt
touch ${File_name_prefix}_2.txt
touch ${File_name_prefix}_3.txt

# Let's list the three files.

# This works.
ls "$File_name_prefix"*
# This works.
ls ${File_name_prefix}*
# This does not work.
ls "${File_name_prefix}*"

# This fails.
find ./ -type f -name '${File_name_prefix}*'
# This fails spectacularly.
find ./ -type f -name ${File_name_prefix}*
# But this works.
find ./ -type f -name "${File_name_prefix}*"

echo "Why?"

# Clean up.
rm ${File_name_prefix}*

exit
```

Comment: For debugging purposes, put `#!/bin/bash -vx` in the first line of your script

Comment: [Pathname expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_06) doesn’t happen within [double-quotes](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_03). It’s that simple. Note that it has nothing to do with neither curly brackets or `ls`.

Comment: bash turns the double quotes into single quotes in that case?

Comment: @Llewen No. Bash never turns any quotes into other quotes. What do you mean?

Comment: When I ran the script with -vx it showd the command with single quotes around it, I guess that was just the output.

Comment: Thank you Biffen, that clears that up.

Comment: @Llewen That’s just a function of the `-x` printing. The arguments sent to the commands (`ls`, `echo`, etc) won’t have any quotes at all (in this case).

Comment: Added find examples to the script.

Comment: @Llewen Regarding `find`: In the first example neither the variable nor the asterisk will be expanded because of the single-quotes and `find` won’t find any files with `${File_name_prefix}` _literally_ in their name. The second example works but not why you think: The shell (Bash) doesn’t expand the asterisk and it gets passed as-is to `find` (inspect with `-x`), then `find` has logic to match it with filenames. The third example fails because the last token gets expanded into _multiple_ tokens and `find` doesn’t understand (compare to `find . -iname foo bar baz`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute a command like first and second examples:

```sh
ls "$File_name_prefix"*
ls ${File_name_prefix}*
```

Command interpreter actually **execute a command with interpolation** according to directory content. A directory is used from command line itself or current directory is used (if command line has relative path),

so it executes like this (assume `$File_name_prefix` is `fp` and directory has files `fp1` `fp2` `fp3`):

```sh
ls fp1 fp2 fp3
```

But for third example command interpreter consider quoted argument as ready to use and **do not applies `*` interpolation**.

so it executes like this:

```sh
ls "fp*"
```

And because there is no file with name `fp*` (with asterisk in name) but only  files `fp1` `fp2` `fp3` (as we assumes) in the directory, therefore it show **empty list** or says that **there is no such file or directory**

Comment: I thought the double quotes allowed for special characters.